# Coldfusion cfscript cookies won't allow for blank expire

Tags: cookies, coldfusion, cfml

I'm trying to use cfscript cookies in CF10 to set a cookie which should be removed when the browser is closed. I can do it via `set-header`, or `<cfcookie>`, but unable to do it through the struct cookie approach.

Does anyone know of a better workaround than using `set-header`? (staying inside cfscript tags)

```
<cfscript>
    // Set-Cookie:TEST1=hello; Expires=Sun, 07-Aug-2044 17:51:26 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly
    cookie.test1 = {value="hello", httponly=true};

    // Set-Cookie:TEST3=hello; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly
    cookie.test3 = {value="hello", httponly=true, expires="0"};

    // Set-Cookie:TEST4=hello; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly
    cookie.test4 = {value="hello", httponly=true, expires="-1"};

    // this throws an exception
    //cookie.test5 = {value="hello", httponly=true, expires=""};
</cfscript>

<!--- Set-Cookie:TEST2=hello2; Path=/; HttpOnly --->
<cfcookie name="test2" value="hello2" httponly="true">
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a need to store this as a cookie instead of as a session scoped variable?  Assuming you aren't referring to your session tracking cookies, this is a simple way to keep track of user state until the session ends.  Which, if properly implemented could/should end when a user closes their browser.

Comment: I'd prefer to use the "client" storage vs the server's storage.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using either **Chrome** or **Firefox** while testing your application. 
I recently faced the same issue. Chrome persist session cookies if you have enabled **continue from where i left off** options from settings. The case is similar with Firefox also. I haven't tested it on IE, so i can not say about its behavior. Expires attribute doesn't work in those cases.
The workaround is that you can use **max-age** attribute. You can give the time to live for cookie in max-age attribute.
And it will work in Chrome and Firefox. IE treat max-age attribute as expires attribute not set. So it will clear cookie when browser restarts. I haven't tested it on Safari.
for reference: [cookie does not expire in firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/970539)

[cookie does not expire in chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128513)

Comment: The problem is not with a specific browser. The problem is the server response coming from Coldfusion.